# Py3 Build a dict of lists from a flat list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list/set of items:
`itemlist = ['aaxx01', 'aaxx02', 'aayy03', 'aayy04','bbxx01', 'bbxx02', 'bbyy03', 'bbyy04','ccxx01', 'ccxx02', 'ccyy03', 'ccyy04']`

Currently using the following long code:

```
items_by_attr = {}
set_of_attributes = {item[0:2] for item in itemlist}
for attr in set_of_attributes:
    items_by_attr[attr] = [
        item for item in itemlist 
       if 'yy' in item and attr in item
    ]
```

to separate into a dict of lists:
    `{'aa': ['aayy03', 'aayy04'], 'bb': ['bbyy03', 'bbyy04'], 'cc': ['ccyy03', 'ccyy04']}`

Is there a simpler language construct to produce the above dict of lists with a single data pass?

Comment: `items_by_attr = defaultdict(list); for item in itemlist: if 'yy' in item:  items_by_attr[item[:2]].append(item)`.

Comment: Thank You.  I was missing SIMPLE